# limit access to unc server to the program

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unc

I am connecting to an unc server (\blablub\share) from my program (written in c++). Right now i am using WNetUseConnection Function to connect to the server. Now i want to limit the access only to the program. Because right now it is possible to access the unc server using the explorer after the connection has been established. But i want to limit the access (especially for file write operations) only to the program.  How do i do that?

Comment: Just don't use WNetUseConnection, refer to files on the share by their UNC name (`\\blablub\share\filename.txt`).  Impersonating another user account could slow the user down as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WNetAddConnection3` and leave `NETRESOURCE::lpLocalName` 0. This does the heavy work of `WNetUseConnection` but doesn't add a drive letter. Therefore, you'll still need to use `\\Server\Share\File` names in your program.

Don't forget to `WNetCancelConnection2` when your program exits. Of course, while your program runs, the connection exists. That's intentional. Security works at user level, not program level. If you really, really don't want this, you'll have to impersonate the user account you use in `WNetAddConnection3`.